# Why did my rMBP13 (late 2013) wake up every minute until battery depleted with reason: ? (Question Mark)?

Tags: sleep-wake, macbook-pro

Can someone help me to diagnose this issue? My new MacBook Pro 13 Retina (8GB / 2.6Ghz / 512GB) awoke in my bag earlier today and apparently did not go back to sleep so ran down the battery and was hot and partially unresponsive when I removed it from my bag.

I ran this command:

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake Reason"
```

I was greeted with this for today:

```
Nov 20 15:12:14 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.LidOpen (User)
Nov 21 01:20:18 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.SleepTimer (SleepTimer)
Nov 21 01:20:44 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 01:21:25 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 01:22:08 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 01:23:13 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 01:23:53 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 01:24:22 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 01:24:58 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 01:25:36 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?

<snip for 30,000 character limit>

Nov 21 17:28:18 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:29:28 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:30:37 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:31:46 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:32:55 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:34:03 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:35:13 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:36:03 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:37:13 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:38:21 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: ?
Nov 21 17:39:08 bishop kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EC.ACAttach (Maintenance)
```

There were 936 entries total with "Wake reason: ?" and that has me more than a little concerned. I'm recently returned to the Mac OS X ecosystem (my last was a Powerbook G4 running 10.2) and have been mostly in the Windows world with some development set-ups in Ubuntu Linux. I'd love some guidance on figuring this one out.

A recent change was that I installed XQuartz 2.7.5 last night to use Inkscape. There were instructions in the Readme about removing /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist using launchctl(1), but I didn't find it listed when I fired it up.

Regardless, my Google-fu did not yield any results that matched this situation well, so I'm appealing to you fine folks.

I've had this machine for 1.5 weeks and this is the first issue of this nature I've experienced. I'm also somewhat concerned about permanent heat damage resulting from being hot in my bag for so long. Any comments on that with your answer to my primary question or in the comments would be greatly appreciated (I understand the rule here is normally one question per... question).

Thank you all!

**EDIT** I thought I would add the cycle that keeps repeating from 
    pmset -g log

```
11/21/13, 4:32:30 PM CST Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:10%)                                  31 secs
11/21/13, 4:32:46 PM CST SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from com.apple.apsd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                    16008 ms
11/21/13, 4:32:46 PM CST WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None
11/21/13, 4:32:55 PM CST Assertions             PID 8249(AddressBookSour) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:30  id:0x1000005d3 [System: No Assertions]
11/21/13, 4:33:01 PM CST Assertions             PID 16(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0xe000005ea [System: No Assertions]
11/21/13, 4:33:01 PM CST DarkWake               DarkWake [CDN]  : Using BATT (Charge:9%)                                    6 secs
11/21/13, 4:33:01 PM CST SlowResponse           Kernel: Response from powerd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                                  16013 ms
11/21/13, 4:33:07 PM CST Assertions             PID 16(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:05  id:0xe000005ea [System: PrevIdle]
11/21/13, 4:33:07 PM CST Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:9%)                                   31 secs
11/21/13, 4:33:21 PM CST SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from com.apple.apsd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                    13803 ms
11/21/13, 4:33:21 PM CST WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None
11/21/13, 4:33:34 PM CST Assertions             PID 8254(AddressBookSour) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:30  id:0x1000005ee [System: No Assertions]
11/21/13, 4:33:38 PM CST Assertions             PID 16(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0xe00000601 [System: No Assertions]
11/21/13, 4:33:38 PM CST DarkWake               DarkWake [CDN]  : Using BATT (Charge:9%)                                    45 secs
11/21/13, 4:33:38 PM CST SlowResponse           Kernel: Response from powerd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                                  13808 ms
11/21/13, 4:34:10 PM CST Assertions             PID 8259(AddressBookSour) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:30  id:0x100000604 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]
11/21/13, 4:34:23 PM CST Assertions             PID 16(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0xe00000601 [System: No Assertions]
11/21/13, 4:34:23 PM CST Sleep                  Maintenance Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:9%)                                   18 secs
11/21/13, 4:34:25 PM CST SlowResponse           PMConnection: Response from com.apple.apsd is slow (powercaps:0x0)                    1750 ms
11/21/13, 4:34:25 PM CST WakeRequests           Clients requested wake events: None
11/21/13, 4:34:41 PM CST Assertions             PID 16(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0xe00000614 [System: No Assertions]
11/21/13, 4:34:41 PM CST DarkWake               DarkWake [CDN]  : Using BATT (Charge:9%)                                    24 secs
11/21/13, 4:34:46 PM CST Assertions             PID 16(powerd) Released     InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:05  id:0xe00000614     [System: PrevIdle PushSrvc kCPU]
```

So, it appears to be the powerd that's causing the issue, but why?

Does this help anyone to help me?

Thank you!!!

**Edit Again**

The saga continues. I've found others seem to be having trouble elsewhere on the interwebs. You can see their adventures [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23594507#23594507).

Now, I've since contacted Apple Support and chatted with a rep there and so far things seem to be working better. However, I'm not going to call this one case closed and will not add an answer just yet.

Here's what's happened:

Chatted with rep and he had me delete the `SystemConfiguration` folder from `/Library/Preferences` and reboot my machine.

Then he said I was on my own and to keep an eye on it, essentially. He was very nice and had the same first name as mine so when he emailed me the chat log it looks like I'm talking to myself.

Not wanting to wait for resolution, I decided to try some testing myself.

First I set my hibernation time to a very low number:

```
sudo pmset -b standbydelay 15
```

Then I slept the machine and let it sit for a while. Typically it would have started the waking thing after 15 seconds when it tried to hibernate. This did not happen. I've actually gotten this to work many times in a row.

I will point out, and I'm not sure if it means anything, but when I first changed my `standbydelay` I got warnings from `pmset` that said: `Display sleep should be lower than system sleep`.

I looks at `pmset -g` and it says that displaysleep was set to 2 while sleep was set to 1. Moreover, after sleep 1 it said `(sleep prevented by apsd, apsd)`. I changed my system sleep and display sleep to make `pmset` happy and afterward ran `pmset -g` again and found that the `(sleep prevented by apsd, apsd)` note was gone from the sleep line. I'm not sure that this is relevant, but I want it known is it's not something I can simply explain.

I will update this after I've used the machine for a while and can say with any confidence that the problem is resolved so that anyone stumbling over this in the future will have more tools at their disposal.

Comment: @fyrephile: I just found this as the top hit for a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wake+reason+question+mark). Do you happened to have any new info to report? My late 2013 MBP is doing the same thing.

Comment: Hello @beporter. There is some further information at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5505142?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with my MacBook Pro, with XQuartz installed too (to use Wireshark).
The issue never happened until I started Wireshark the first time with XQuartz. Maybe it could be the cause of the issue.

I removed XQuartz but the issue continues to remain. It happen not all the time but sometimes the issues appears again. Apple support have absolutely no idea why it happens and they proposed me to format disk and reinstall OS X. This would be a solution for a Windows operating system... for now they don't really want to investigate this issue as I can see (even if there are more people having it with different types of MAC products...). It looks clearly like a bug in OS X

I try to analyse which processes are running when issue happens in order to determine which one could be involved

Wait and see...

Comment: That's very possible. I have found on the discussion thread that I referenced above that there are other people having the same issue with XQuartz installed.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Avast solved the issue. It's not a good solution but for now it works. I don't think Avast is the cause of the problem but coupled with XQuartz it could have triggered something nasty in OS X.

Apple technical support told me to wait on next system updates, maybe they have found something. I hope so :)

Comment: Never ever trust Updates to fix problems ;D
Especially not these kind of problems. That's simply too specific.