# iTunes, even when not playing, keeping my computer from sleeping automatically

Tags: itunes, macos, sleep-wake, pmset

I'm using the default Energy Save preferences on a MBPro running Mavericks. If iTunes is running, my computer will not go to sleep automatically even if iTunes is not playing (e.g., if I stop it by pressing Command-.). I've tried all of the following without success:

- [Resetting the NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) as recommended [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5357)
- [Resetting the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) as recommended [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5357)
- [sudo pmset touch](http://www.robmeerman.co.uk/osx/start)
- [sudo mv /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist ~kuzzooroo/Desktop](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23594507)
- [sudo mv /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration ~kuzzooroo/Desktop/](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111417/why-did-my-rmbp13-late-2013-wake-up-every-minute-until-battery-depleted-with-r)
- [Reinstalling iTunes](http://help.overdrive.com/customer/portal/articles/1481557-how-to-reinstall-itunes-for-mac)
- [Running Disk Utility's Repair Disk Permissions feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452)

Here's some `pmset` output from while iTunes is running:

```
$ pmset -g | grep " sleep"
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod)
$ pmset -g assertions | tail
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 198(coreaudiod): [0x0000000100000159] 00:04:37 NoIdleSleepAssertion named: "com.apple.audio.'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,1:0'.noidlesleep"
   pid 74(hidd): [0x0000000a00000167] 00:04:23 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle"
    Timeout will fire in 110 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
Kernel Assertions: 0xc=USB,BT-HID
   id=501  level=255 0x4=USB mod=5/19/14, 21:55 description=XHC1 owner=AppleUSBXHCI
   id=502  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=12/31/69, 19:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=BNBTrackpadDevice
```

And here's what I see after quitting iTunes:

```
$ pmset -g | grep " sleep"
 sleep                1
$ pmset -g assertions | tail
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 74(hidd): [0x0000000a00000167] 00:06:25 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle"
    Timeout will fire in 104 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
Kernel Assertions: 0xc=USB,BT-HID
   id=501  level=255 0x4=USB mod=5/19/14, 21:55 description=XHC1 owner=AppleUSBXHCI
   id=502  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=12/31/69, 19:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=BNBTrackpadDevice
```

I usually have iTunes running and would prefer that the computer sleep even if I forget to quit iTunes (and forget to put the computer to sleep manually).

What is the next thing I should try? Thanks!

Comment: you have done a lots of good work already. doing the disk utility permissions repair would not harm.

Comment: Thank you @Buscar웃. I tried Repair Permissions and unfortunately it did not solve the problem. I've updated the question to reflect that. Is there anything left to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called Apple and interestingly the stuff they advised me to do was nothing I'd found anywhere online. They said the issues with coreaudiod are generally caused by iTunes extensions. They had me open up Activity Monitor and advised me to kill a process called [AccuBeatMix](http://www.wildbits.com/accubeatmix/), and that made the issue go away. I've got an e-mail out to the maker of AccuBeatMix to see if there's a workaround and will post here if there is. Until then I've just got it uninstalled (moved it out of `/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins`).